# Has the SDLC of Stack Overflow been discussed anywhere?

Tags: discussion

Is there anywhere where the Software Development Life Cycle (SDLC) of Stack Overflow has been discussed? From the planning phase to implementation to deployment?

Whats and Whys:

- Language
- Database system
- Server
- Other API's and Tools

Stack Overflow is a well planned site and I believe it would help programmers a lot to read an article about it.

Comment: +1 would like to see this too.

Comment: What is SDLC?

Comment: Software design life cycle?

Comment: development?

Comment: Still, no one will tel me what SDLC stands for?  Sure I could google it...but doesn't someone want me to upvote their comment?

Comment: SDLC - Software Development Life Cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog was already mentioned. Here's a post with some technical details and further links: [What Was Stack Overflow Built Width?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

Comment: Build width? Sure it's pretty wide but I think you made a spelling mistake. One that is too amusing for me to correct ;)

Answer (score 10):

Jeff keeps a [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) about the construction of the site and him and Joel have a [weekly podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html) where they discuss designing the site, among other things.

There is also another site, [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), which is for meta discussion about this site. This question should have been asked there.

A moderator will be by shortly to move it.

Comment: sheesh, way to go, party pooper :P

Comment: Party Pooper? :( If/When the question gets moved to Meta, you can have your party there. The answer was a direct response to the question though: is there anywhere this is discussed? Answer: Yes.

Comment: Arguably, Meta is *the* place for parties.

Comment: ...parties with F-bombs, ponies, and cat pinatas.

Comment: and mmm-bacon. Shog9 and TheTXI would agree.

Answer (score 1):

Language: ASP.net
Database: I think MS SQL
Server: Windows Server
Other API's and Tools: ???

Comment: That's the tech stack, not the actual life cycle and process flow for development ...

Answer (score 0):

While this is a [talk about SO by Joel Spolsky](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ) it might be of some interest in relation to SF too, as he talks a lot about planning, implementation and deployment or the site.