# Why isn't reputation gained/lost by a question undone when a question is migrated between sites?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, migration

I answered a question on SO yesterday, which was later migrated to meta ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288308/), [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14943/)).

I gained 46 reputation on this answer, and it remains on my account even though the question is now on meta.

Shouldn't this reputation have been undone when the question was moved, or is there some sort of scheduled recalculation of reputation I'm unaware of?

**Fake Edit:**
When I tried to post this, it was originally rejected since it didn't include a tag of bug, feature-request, discussion, or support. Where is this documented, and why aren't we told BEFORE submitting?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6647/require-one-of-the-bold-border-tags-on-new-metaso-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rep recalcs are cripplingly expensive, and would destroy performance on the production site if done dynamically.

Thus, they are done offline, and not on any official schedule as of yet.

Comment: So, does this mean that the positive rep from an upvote to a migrated question IS lost, but not lost until later?

Answer (score 2):

There is a offline rep recalculation which is also used to check for bogus voting patterns. However if I recall migrations do not preserve the initial rep even after being moved. Jeff covered the topic in detail [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/).